# TabControl not showing content based on view model type

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I have a TabControl which defines some data templates to show content based on the selected tab.

```
    <TabControl 
        Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ExerciseViewModels}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedExercise}">
        
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="local:SubtractExerciseViewModel">
                <local:SubtractUserControl/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="local:SumExerciseViewModel">
                <local:SubtractUserControl/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        
    </TabControl>
```

But when I run, the selected tab shows the name of the ViewModel (thus the DataTemplate for the specific type is not used).

[image]

What am I missing?

PS: Using MvvmLight but not really of any relevance. All the view models obviously exist (see screenshot, it has the reference to an object of type SuusRekenWonder.SumExerciseViewModel). So I am doing something wrong in XAML. But what?

Answer (score 0):

In your `TabControl`-Resources you have to use x:Type for your DataType. Then your Resources look like:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SubtractExerciseViewModel}">
    <local:SubtractUserControl/>
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SumExerciseViewModel}">
    <local:SubtractUserControl/>
  </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.Resources>
```